# Linux embeddable cheap rack server

Tags: linux, rack

I want to embed my network connectivity application into a linux installed rack-mount server and sell it bundled. I googled some but couldn't figured out which it would be?

Do you have any experiences with these types of hardware and recommend some?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly what the requirements of your application are... You just have to start it off a small storage device and that's it, no need for more disk space? Are you going to do logging?

Dell, IBM, HP all have rack-mount servers, which come with no HDD, just a small 16-64MB internal flash disk, which is typically used to install VMware ESXi Embedded. Maybe you can use one of these servers, if they're not out of your budget.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like an 'appliance' device, then all you need to do is to buy a off-the-shelf 1U/2U [rackmount](http://us.enlightcorp.com/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?ID=144) server and load it up with your application. There are several vendors that sell it.

Answer (score 0):

depending how cpu intensive your app is - maybe some [atom rack server](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2012710008%201076148674&name=Intel%20Atom)? [disclaimer: i never used this server, just read some reviews].

if price is not your concern - i'd go with dell / hp / lenovo 1u rack server and got reasonable support with it to save you trouble. [or you can as well buy spare unit...]